# Neo4j : Find a relationship and the 5 relationships before it

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm writing a blog post on using graphs to identify credit card thieves. My data model is this : **people** are connected to **merchants** through **transactions**. Transactions have a time and a status ("disputed" or "undisputed"). A fraudulent transaction is a transaction that has the property "disputed". Simple stuff.

- People have a "Person" label and the following properties : id, code,
  name, label, gender, age
- Merchants have a "Merchant" label and the
  following properties : id, code, name, street, address
- Only one kind of relationship : "HAS_BOUGHT_AT". It has the following properties :
  amount, time, status

I'm trying to write a Cypher query that identifies the fraudulent transactions in a graph and grabs the last 5 transactions the customer did before the fraudulent transaction.

Here is what I've got so far :

```
MATCH (victim:person)-[r:HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(merchant)
WHERE r.status = "Disputed"
MATCH victim-[t:HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(othermerchants)
WHERE t.status = "Undisputed" AND t.time < r.time
RETURN DISTINCT victim.name as customer_name, othermerchants.name as store_name, t.amount as amount, t.time as transaction_time
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

I have two problems :
- the query returns transactions involving people who are not victims
- I don't know how to limit the results to the 5 latest transactions

Any one knows what I could do?

Best,

Jean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE your first question, can you give more insight/detail as to your actual data model and what's in the graph?  How do you define what a "victim" is?  Based on your current query, a "victim" is someone who has had a "disputed" transaction.  When you say your query is returning people who are not victims, what kind of people (or "person"s) are being returned?

As for your second question, try this:

```
MATCH (victim:person)-[r:HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(merchant)
WHERE r.status = "Disputed"
MATCH victim-[t:HAS_BOUGHT_AT]->(othermerchants)
WHERE t.status = "Undisputed" AND t.time < r.time
WITH victim, othermerchants, t ORDER BY t.time DESC LIMIT 5
RETURN DISTINCT victim.name as customer_name, othermerchants.name as store_name, t.amount    as amount, t.time as transaction_time
ORDER BY t.time DESC
```

(Note the "WITH" and the "LIMIT".  The second "ORDER BY" may become moot.)

Comment: Thank you. A victim would be someone involved in a "disputed" transaction. After double checking it looks like the first query is returning only victims. The query you propose looks great. Only problem is I end up with only 2 results (12 without the limit clause). Any ideas about what's going on?

Comment: It could be that the result set on which the "DISTINCT" is operating contains only 2 such "distinct" results, and that removing the limit of 5 exposes 12 distinct results.  To confirm, try removing the "DISTINCT" and see how many results you get back with and without the LIMIT and examine the actual values returned.

Comment: I removed the DISTINCT and got 5 occurences of the 2 results. I removed DISTINCT and the LIMIT and got 53 occurences of the 12 results.

Comment: Then that should prove what I was suggesting: Getting 5 occurrences instead of 2 by removing the DISTINCT shows the limiting to 5 results, and that DISTINCT is removing 3 duplicates.  It sounds like this answers your question. :) If so, please do mark my answer as accepted.  Thanks and good luck!